# Jquery table td with children.each()

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table like so:

```
  <tr>
      <td><td>
      <td id="some_id" name="some_name"><td>
      <td id="some_other_id" name="some_other_name"></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
```

and now I want to get all elemtens inside this  without the first and the last children to change the id. I use this code:

```
    var i = 0;
    $(changeRow).children().not(':first').not(':last').children().each(function() {
         var replacementField = 'column-' + i++ + '-field-' + ndx;
         $(this).id = $(this).id.replace(replacementField);
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: it should be `$(this).id` > `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: changeRow is not defined

Comment: changeRow get the <tr> tag infornt of var i = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
$('tr td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function(){
    var replacementField = 'column-' + i++ + '-field-' + ndx;
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(replacementField));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what is `changeRow` ? an id ? a object ?

So you can change your selector like maximkou say by `tr td` => select all `td` children in `tr` elements.

With your selector, you call `.children()` once too often and get the children of `td`.

And if you just want to replace the id with a new one, you can simplify the replace of your id in one call.

```
var i = 0;
$("tr td").not(':first').not(':last').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'column-' + i++ + '-field' + ndx);
});
```

See this code work on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AAshX/1/